# Java Binary Search Tree - Recursive Void Copy Method

Tags: java, recursion, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I need to create a recursive copy method for a binary search tree from scratch for an assignment of mine. The method should copy each item in a given BinarySearchTree object to the calling BinarySearchTree object. Only problem is that the method must be a `void` and everything I've looked up on this subject seems to utilize different return types to get this done.

I don't really know how to even start with something like this, all I have is the prettymuch empty shell of the method and it's wrapper. I'm not sure if the parameters in the private method are correct but it was my best guess as a start.

```
public void copy(BinarySearchTree<E> bst2){
        copy(bst2, root, bst2.root);
    }

private void copy(BinarySearchTree<E> bst2, Node node1, Node node2){
    }
```

I'd appreciate any and all help.

Thanks!

Comment: Well, this question is not explaining much of the problem. The only hint I could give would be that if you can't handle the result via returns, you'll have to alter an already given structure and hand it to the method via parameters.

Comment: I think you might want to look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5372512/java-binary-search-tree-recursive-copy-tree?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Immediate thought is (rough pseudocode ahead):

```
class Tree {
     //stuff in the tree with a root node, etc...

     copyTree(Node parentTreeNode, Node copyTreeNode) {
          if(copyTreeNode == null)
              return;
          parentTreeNode = clone(copyTreeNode) //clone just copies the node's values into the node.
          if(copyTreeNode.leftChild != null) {
              parentTreeNode.leftChild = new Node();
              copyTree(parentTreeNode.leftChild, copyTreeNode.leftChild);
          }
          if(copyTreeNode.rightChild != null) {
              parentTreeNode.rightChild = new Node();
              copyTree(parentTreeNode.rightChild, copyTreeNode.rightChild);
          }
     }
}
```

And you would just call this with the two root nodes and let it recurse and it builds the tree for you.

So, if the base case gets triggered (the current node is null) then you skip that node by returning and move on in the recursion process (the base case is important in recursive techniques, otherwise you get infinite recursion). So, we start with the root node, copy it (if it's not null), and then move to the left subtree, assuming it's also not null. We pause in this method, call the method on the subtree, which "pauses" there and causes on the left.... When it returns back all the way down, each place it had "paused" resumes, moving to the right child on each of those nodes with the same procedure. Once the left subtree recurses on itself, we resume in the top node and move to the right subtree to do the same thing there (just like it did in all the children nodes, recursively). When it's all done, it just returns normally.

Recursion isn't particularly difficult, but it does take some practice to understand at first.

This is a rough idea and hasn't been tested, but that's roughly how I'd do it. It's probably worth noting that this style of handling it won't guarantee that the trees are the same if the main tree already had data in it, or you handed a node other than the root node. But it would be the same from below that node.